Is there a prime number $p$ such that $p$ divides the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$?
Several people must have asked this before, but anyway:
Is there a prime number $p$ such that $p$ divides the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$?
From the asymptotics that we obtain from the class number formula, it seems that such a prime should not exist. However, does anyone know of a proof or a relevant reference that addresses this question?

We can assume that $p>3$. Let $D\in\{-p,-4p\}$ be the discriminant of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$. By Dirichlet's class number formula, the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ equals
$$h(D)=\frac{1}{\pi}|D|^{1/2}L(1,\chi_D),$$
where $\chi_D$ is the primitive quadratic character of conductor $D$. Hence, by a result of Louboutin (2004),
$$h(D)\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}|D|^{1/2}(\log|D|+2+\gamma-\log\pi).$$
The right-hand side is less than $|D|/4$, hence the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ is not divisible by $p$.

From the bound proved in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291124/an-upper-bound-for-class-numbers-of-imaginary-quadratic-fields it follows that the class number is less than $p$.
